# Android SQLite: Doubts in Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am currently learning android SQLite database programming. While reading [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) tutorial from here. I came across a section of code,

```
getContact()
    // Getting single contact
public Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}
```

**My Questions**

**Question 1**
If this code returns the query ,

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Why do we move the cursor to the first row in this line ?

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

**Question 2**

What does this code do ?

```
Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
```

I read the official documentation but still could not understand. Can some one explain with a simple example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Because Cursor is set before first row element initially.
Question 2: It gets Strings from row which is set as current in cursor object from columns (every row consists of columns) with numbers 0, 1 and 2. Then it uses them to create contact object.

Comment: The `cursor` has my exact query So why do we move the cursor to the First row of the DB records ?

Comment: Cursor object contains results of your query as a list of rows elements. Initially cursor is set to point to the position before the first row element. So you have to move it forward by one position to point to first element by `moveToNext()` method or tell it to position itself on first row by `moveToFirst` method.

Comment: z Ok got it.So this line`Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2)` will return the `KEY_ID,KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO` from the query result right ?

Comment: thanks a lot Bro. Thanks a lot for confirming my assumptions. I am now very clear about it.